# Add classes with generic interface to DI with reflection

Tags: dependency-injection, reflection, .net-6.0

how do I register each implementation of `IMyInterface<T>` to the DI container?

Instead of having to manually register each class that implements a generic interface I want reflection to take care of this on startup.

```cs
public interface IMyInterface<T> { }

public class Foo : IMyInterface<Bar> { }

public class Baz : IMyInterface<A> { }
```

How do I register `Foo` and `Baz` as `services.AddTransient<IMyInterface<Bar>, Foo>()` using reflection?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Steven I tried but without any success. I could only get all classes the are implementing `IMyInterface<>` but not further then that. Trying to get the first generic parameters also results in a fail because then you are trying to get it from the class type, instead of the generic interface. I hoped that someone could just put a answer because I've seen some libraries that seem to do this on startup. For example MediatR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-Registering your types is done in three steps:

1. Request types from the type system
2. Filtering the types you want to register
3. Loop through the list and register them

Requesting types from the type system can be done through the `Assembly` API, typically by calling `Assembly.GetTypes()` or `Assembly.GetExportedTypes()` (look at the documentation which method suits you best). But first you need to access the `Assembly` instance or instances. This can be done using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to get all *currently loaded* assemblies (warning: this might not be *all* assemblies your application needs, or you can get the assembly of a specific type, for instance by calling `typeof(Foo).Assembly`. This is useful if you know that all types live in the same assembly.

This leads to the following code:

```cs
var types =
    from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from type in assembly.GetTypes()
    select type;
```

Next, you want to filter out the types that do not implement `IMyInterface<T>`. This is the most tricky part, because Reflection and generic types can be a PITA. However, a filter such as the following will get you started:

```cs
var registrations =
    from type in types
    where !type.IsAbstract
    where !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition
    let services =
        from iface in type.GetInterfaces()
        where iface.IsGenericType
        where iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMyInterface<>)
        select iface
    from service in services
    select new { service, type };
```

This code:

- filters out all abstract types (interfaces and abstract classes) as they can't be registered
- filters out all generic type definitions, such as `Bar<T>`, because they typically require special attention and registration.
- Gets all the interfaces of the type that implement a closed version of `IMyInterface<T>`.
- Each returned interface results in a item in the `registrations` collection. If a type doesn't implement `IMyInterface<T>`, it will not be part of the `registrations` collection and, therefore, not registered (see below). In case a type implements `IMyInterface<T>` multiple times, it gets a registration for each closed version of that interface (which can be very handy, depending on your needs).

Now you have a list of registrations to make. The remaining task is the actual registration of these service-to-implementation mappings, which is actually the easy part:

```cs
foreach (var reg in registrations)
{
    services.AddTransient(reg.service, reg.type);
}
```

Et voilà. There you have it. All your non-generic implementations of `IMyInterface<T>` are registered by their closed `IMyInterface<T>`.